# How to fix "Cannot find board_env.xml" with FPGA boards installation

Tags: intel, fpga

> Cannot find board_env.xml in /opt/intelFPGA_pro/18.1/hld/board/a10_ref/linux64/lib

Answer (score 1):

**Error: "cannot find board_env.xml in ..."**

**Description**

When using Intel® FPGA OpenCL™ SDK 18.1, customer may get error information as "cannot find board_env.xml" during kernel compilation flow when a relative path is used to specify the  -board-package parameter.

**For example:**

```
aoc -no-auto-migrate boardtest.cl -o boardtest_a10soc_noautomigrate/boardtest.aocx -board-package=./board/a10soc
```

**Workaround/Fix**

To work around this problem use an absolute path for the the board-package.

```
aoc -no-auto-migrate boardtest.cl -o boardtest_a10soc_noautomigrate/boardtest.aocx -board-package=/<quartus installation>/hld/board/a10soc
```

For more reference please [click](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/programmable/support/support-resources/knowledge-base/embedded/2019/-error--cannot-find-boardenv-xml-in-bsp-location.html)

Comment: Thank you!                                                   and when I try to work around problem use an absolute path for the the board-package this Error: Invalid kernel file boardtest.cl: No such file or directory is displayed. I have set the environmental variable to the path of my installation. I don't know basic problem with it?